# Why use async/await, it makes code work like sync

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

If you use promise's `then()` syntax, you can truly run codes concurrently.

See this example.

```js
async function asyncFunc() {
  return '2';
}

console.log('1')
asyncFunc().then(result => console.log(result))
console.log('3')
```

this prints `1` -> `3` -> `2` because `asyncFunction()` runs in "async" and rest of code (`'3'`) runs without delay.

But if you use `async`/`await` syntax, doesn't it work like plain ordinary "sync" code?

```js
async function asyncFunc() {
  return '2';
}

console.log('1')
const result = await asyncFunc()
console.log(result)
console.log('3')
```

this would print `1`->`2`->`3` because it "defers" rest of the code to "await" asyncFunction()

So I'm curious about the purpose of `async`/`await` syntax. I guess it allows you to use async functions like sync function. With `async`/`await`, I can easily see how my code runs because it has the same flow as plain sync code. But then, why not just use sync code in the first place?

But I'm sure I'm missing something here right? What is the purpose of `async`/`await` syntax?

Comment: Because you don't always control how functions you call are defined. Suppose `asyncFunc` is provided by a library you cannot change. Then there's no way to get rid of  the await.

Comment: "*But then, why not just use sync code in the first place?*" Because not everything is synchronous. Network requests are quite famously asynchronous - it's the **A** in **A**JAX

Comment: I'm so sad about down votes... althought my question seems too basic, I've described my thoughts well with examples... thanks for comments guys. Then can I say `async`/`await` keyword exists to control async functions in synchronous manner?

Comment: You could have an async function that saves a row into a database. You might want to wait for that to finish to get the ID of the newly inserted row to do something else or you might want to just shove a bunch of parallel calls into a `Promise.all([...])`. In the first example you don't want to have to layer on all the `.then()` bits, so the await sugar is helpful to greatly simplify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of `async/await` is as follows:

It is a syntactic sugar for promises. It allows to use async code (like Web Api's - AJAX, DOM api's etc.) in synchronous order.

You ask "But then, why not just use sync code in the first place?" - because in your example you forced a sync code to be returned in a promise, basically you made it async, but it could run as sync in the first place, but there are Web APIs as mentioned above, that work ONLY ASYNC (meaning you have to wait for them to be executed), that's why you cannot turn them in sync "in the first place" :)

When JavaScript encounters the await expression, it pauses the async function execution and waits until the promise is fulfilled (the promise successfully resolved) or rejected (an error has occurred), then it continues the execution where it pauses in that function... The promise can be code from JS engine (as in your case) or it can be from another place like browser apis (truly async).

Comment: "When JavaScript encounters the await expression, it pauses the async function execution and waits until the promise is fulfilled (the promise successfully resolved) or rejected (an error has occurred), then it continues the execution where it pauses in that function."

Thats why I have the same question. Once we met AWAIT - this means that the function will run in SYNC mode. So, IMHO async keyword in this case is NONSENSE.